# Implementing Newton's Method in R using a While Loop

Tags: r, while-loop, newtons-method

```
g <- function(x) {
  log(x)/(1+x)
}

gPrime <- function(x) {
  (1 + x - x*log(x))/(x^3 + 2*x^2 + x)
}

guess <- 1.5
tolerance <- .00001

root <- function(g, gPrime, guess, tolerance) 
  {
  x <-  guess
  while (abs(g(x)) > tolerance) 
    {
    x <-  x - g(x)/(gPrime)
  }
  x
}

root(g, gPrime, guess, tolerance)
```

I got this code from a previous stackoverflow thread but for my function it only works for the real root of 1 and no other value. The following error shows for any other value then 1

```
Error in g(x)/(gPrime) : non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

Could the error be because of the log function because I tried a function without a log and it worked fine for any initial guess

Comment: you need     `x <-  x - g(x)/gPrime(x)`

Comment: that simple, thank you

Comment: Or just use this: `uniroot(g, c(0.1, 10))`

Comment: @Dave2e thank you but my professor does not only use of predefined functions in R such as uniroot